# Setting project item subproperties in IWizard?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions

I have a custom item template that I am adding to a Sharepoint project. I need to ensure that my modules are only associated with my feature, even if the project already contains other features.

Replacing IDs in `projectItemReference` elements within .feature files is trivial to do by modifying the `replacementsDictionary` in the `RunStarted` method.

For example, I have the following `SampleModule_WebParts.feature` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<feature xmlns:dm0="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2008/DslTools/Core" dslVersion="1.0.0.0" Id="$SampleFeatureID$" activateOnDefault="false" description="Sample Web Part" featureId="$SampleFeatureID$" scope="Site" solutionId="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" title="Contoso Intranet Sample Module Web Parts" version="" deploymentPath="$SharePoint.Project.FileNameWithoutExtension$_$SharePoint.Feature.FileNameWithoutExtension$" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2008/SharePointTools/FeatureModel">
  <projectItems>
    <projectItemReference itemId="$SampleModuleID$" />
  </projectItems>
</feature>
```

Replacing `$SampleModuleID$` and `$SampleFeatureID$` by modifying the `replacementsDictionary` in the `IWizard.RunStarted` method is trivial. But how can I modify the generated `.csproj` file snippet?

```
<None Include="Features\SampleModule_WebParts\SampleModule_WebParts.feature">
  <FeatureId>{78185D58-6398-4ED2-B0D0-3DC20946FF8F}</FeatureId>
</None>
<Compile Include="SPItems\SampleModule\SampleWebPart\SampleWebPart.cs" />
<Compile Include="SPItems\SampleModule\SampleWebPart\SampleWebPartUserControl.ascx.cs">
  <DependentUpon>SampleWebPartUserControl.ascx</DependentUpon>
  <SubType>ASPXCodeBehind</SubType>
</Compile>
<Compile Include="SPItems\SampleModule\SampleWebPart\SampleWebPartUserControl.ascx.designer.cs">
  <DependentUpon>SampleWebPartUserControl.ascx.cs</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
<None Include="SPItems\SampleModule\SampleWebPart\SampleWebPart.webpart" />
<None Include="SPItems\SampleModule\SampleWebPart\SharePointProjectItem.spdata">
  <SharePointProjectItemId>{D982D304-E7FB-4E8C-899B-7D4096A55892}</SharePointProjectItemId>
</None>
```

In this case, I'd need to set the `FeatureId` and `SharePointProjectItemId` properties for the `.feature` and `.spdata` items. If I don't do anything, Visual Studio will autogenerate those GUIDs, but they won't match what I have in my `replacementsDictionary`. And that in turn leads to a broken reference in my `.feature` file and my module may get associated with the wrong feature.

How can I set those custom properties so that they are persisted into the `.csproj` file when the user saves it? `IWizard.ProjectItemFinishedGenerating` seems like the correct method to implement and I can inspect the `ProjectItem` parameter to figure out when the `.spdata` and `.feature` files have been generated, but *what* should I do there to set the `FeatureId` and `SharePointProjectItemId` properties?

Comment: ProjectItem -> Properties -> find by name -> set value (I did that for TreatWarningAsErrors property.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to convert the `Project` reference into an `ISharePointProject` and calling 
`ISharepointProject.Synchronize()`. After that I could traverse the SharePoint project's object model.

```
var sp = project.DTE as Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop.IServiceProvider;
var projectService = new ServiceProvider(sp).GetService(typeof(ISharePointProjectService)) as ISharePointProjectService;
var sharepointProject = projectService.Convert<Project, ISharePointProject>(project);
sharepointProject.Synchronize();
```

After finding the my module and my feature from the collections returned by the `ProjectItems` and `Features` properties, I could simply associate the module with the feature:

```
sampleFeature.ProjectItems.Add(sampleModule);
```

Because I can fix the references programmatically, I can leave the old module GUID in the `.feature` file and clean up the invalid association by modifying the `sampleFeature.Model.ProjectItems` collection.

```
var invalidSampleModuleAssociation = (from projectItem in sampleFeature.Model.ProjectItems
                                      where projectItem.ItemId == originalSampleModuleID
                                      select projectItem).First();
sampleFeature.Model.ProjectItems.Remove(invalidSampleModuleAssociation);
```

Finally, I need to remove my module from any other features that the project might have, because Visual Studio automatically associates a new module with the first feature with an appropriate scope.

```
var unneededAssociations = (from otherFeature in sharepointProject.Features
                            where otherFeature.Name != sampleFeature.Name
                            from projectItem in otherFeature.ProjectItems
                            where projectItem.Name == sampleModule.Name
                            select new
                            {
                                Feature = otherFeature,
                                ModuleToRemove = projectItem
                            }).ToArray();
foreach (var moduleAssociation in unneededAssociations)
{
    moduleAssociation.Feature.ProjectItems.Remove(moduleAssociation.ModuleToRemove);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you can make replacements also in any file, including the .csproj (in both filename and content)

If you have the Guids you wanna replace in the replacementDictionary, simply check the .vstemplate in order to be sure that file replacement is true:

```
<Project
    File="MyProject.proj"
    TargetFileName="$safeprojectname$.csproj"
    ReplaceParameters="true">
</Project>
```

And edit the .csproj properly, replacing the Guids:

```
<None Include="Features\SampleModule_WebParts\SampleModule_WebParts.feature">
  <FeatureId>{$SampleFeatureID$}</FeatureId>
</None>
<Compile Include="SPItems\SampleModule\SampleWebPart\SampleWebPart.cs" />
<Compile Include="SPItems\SampleModule\SampleWebPart\SampleWebPartUserControl.ascx.cs">
  <DependentUpon>SampleWebPartUserControl.ascx</DependentUpon>
  <SubType>ASPXCodeBehind</SubType>
</Compile>
<Compile Include="SPItems\SampleModule\SampleWebPart\SampleWebPartUserControl.ascx.designer.cs">
  <DependentUpon>SampleWebPartUserControl.ascx.cs</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
<None Include="SPItems\SampleModule\SampleWebPart\SampleWebPart.webpart" />
<None Include="SPItems\SampleModule\SampleWebPart\SharePointProjectItem.spdata">
  <SharePointProjectItemId>{$SampleModuleID$}</SharePointProjectItemId>
</None>
```

**Important! replacementDictionary, as IDictionaryl is case sensitive!!**

Comment: You can only modify the .csproj if you're also creating a custom project template that includes the .csproj file. The template in my example is an item template that could be added to any SharePoint project, so I can't use replacementsDictionary to modify the .csproj file.